# Structuring a Vuex module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am having some trouble in trying to keep my Vuex modules clean and I was hoping to receive some insight on how to improve this. I have already split up some mutations and am using actions to compose multiple mutations so I guess that is a good start.

In most examples I see super clean mutations and I have those as well but a lot I needs checks with if statements or other side effects. To provide examples:

**My action:**

```
setFilteredData({ state, commit }, payload) {
    commit('setFilteredData', payload);

    // Check if we need to split up the data into 'hotels' and 'nearby_hotels'.
    if (state.filteredData.find(hotel => hotel.nearby_city)) {
        commit('splitHotelsAndNearbyHotels', state.filteredData);
    }
}
```

**My mutation:**

```
splitHotelsAndNearbyHotels(state, payload) {
    // Chunk it up into hotels and nearby hotels.
    const composed = groupBy(payload, 'nearby_city');

    if (composed.true) {
        composed.true.forEach((hotel) => {
            if (hotel.isFirst) hotel.isFirst = false;
        });

        composed.true[0].isFirst = true;

        // Merge them back together in the right order.
        state.filteredData = composed.false.concat(composed.true);
    }
}
```

In this example if my array of objects contains a hotel with `hotel.nearby_city` set to `true` it will perform the commit of `splitHotelsAndNearbyHotels`.

The code is not transparent enough. The `if` statement inside the action does not feel right and I would like my mutation to be cleaner.

I have thought about splitting up my `splitHotelsAndNearbyHotels` into separate functions but I have no idea where to place those. Simply putting them inside the Vuex file does not feel like a big improvement putting them in a separate file could be an option I guess.

How could I clean up my file to improve the readability? Perhaps someone can show me a Vuex example which does not have an ideal scenario like what I am dealing with.

Comment: I don't think neither the action nor the mutation is really a problem, if anything, their naming. Perhaps there is a better name for `setFilteredData`?

Comment: One approach would be to just have one array of hotels for your state, and computed properties for getting each filtered subset of hotels. This makes the code simpler so there's one array to search in when you need to mutate a hotel, regardless of type. I'm assuming you're just toggling between preset filters for a list you're displaying, so more context is needed. The right approach will vary based on your needs. This is a rather open ended question lacking important context. Explain why you want to "set" filtered hotels, to me that sounds like a "get". Its like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can move your actions code into getters, it's more clean to use single source and filter it on getter.
But if you insist using action you can move your mutation code inside on action, and restructure your actions code just like this:

> Helper.js

This is for provide data and helper functions:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

const payloadData = [
    {"name":"A", "nearby_city":true, "isFirst":true},
    {"name":"B", "nearby_city":false, "isFirst":false},
    {"name":"C", "nearby_city":false, "isFirst":false},
    {"name":"D", "nearby_city":true, "isFirst":false}
];

// assumed nearby_city is boolean
const isNearby = (hotels) => { return !!hotels.find(hotel => hotel.nearby_city === true) };
const groupBy = (items, key) => { return _.groupBy(items, item => item[key]) };
```

> Mutations.js

This is your mutation looks now:

```
const mutations = {
    setfilteredData : (state, hotels) => {
        state.filteredHotels = hotels || [];
    },
}
```

> Actions.js

And this is your actions, it's fine without moving your functions into separate files.

```
// separate filter function
const filterNearby = (payload) => {
    if(isNearby(payload) === false){
        return payload;
    }

    const composed = groupBy(payload, 'nearby_city');
    composed.true.forEach((hotel) => {
        if (hotel.isFirst) hotel.isFirst = false;
    });

    composed.true[0].isFirst = true;
    return composed.false.concat(composed.true);
};

const actions = {
    setfilteredData: ({state, commit}, payload) => {
        /**
         * Using separate filter function
         */
        commit('setfilteredData', filterNearby(payload));
        return;

        /**
         * Using restructured code
         */

        // Check if we need to split up the data into 'hotels' and 'nearby_hotels'.
        if(isNearby(payload) === false){
            commit('setfilteredData', payload);
            return;
        }

        // Chunk it up into hotels and nearby hotels.
        const composed = groupBy(payload, 'nearby_city');

        composed.true.forEach((hotel) => {
            if (hotel.isFirst) hotel.isFirst = false;
        });

        composed.true[0].isFirst = true;

        // Merge them back together in the right order.
        commit('setfilteredData', composed.false.concat(composed.true));
    }
};
```